# how to use "ezplot" to plot implicit functions?

Tags: matlab

How Can I use `ezplot` to plot something like this:

```
syms Vg L a b z c

c=sym('a*Vg+z');

A=sym('a*Vg+b+c*L');

A=subs(A,[a b z],[1 2 3]);

ezplot(A)
```

where I want to plot `Vg` versus `L`.

The point is that `A` contains another sym which is `c`.

The above code yields an error.

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: How do you intend to plot a graph with 30 parameters? How should it look like?

Answer (score 2):

The error when running your example is quite telling;

> *"The number of variables **must not exceed two** when plotting an equation"*.

In your case, you're attempting to implicitly plot a function which contains three variables; the output of your symbolic equation is

```
...

A =

    Vg + L*c + 2
```

Now, from the reference documentation of `ezplot`:

> **Passing Additional Arguments**
>
> If your function has additional parameters, for example `k` in `myfun`:
>
> ```
> function z = myfun(x,y,k)
> z = x.^k - y.^k - 1;
> ```
>
> then you can use an anonymous function to specify that parameter:
>
> ```
> ezplot(@(x,y)myfun(x,y,2))
> ```

---

Hence, one alternative is to can create a function for this 3-variable expression:

```
% myfun.m
function z = myfun(Vg,L,c)
    z = Vg + L.*c + 2;
end
```

And thereafter use `ezplot` by calling this function with an anonymous function for the first two parameters (`@(Vg,L)`), and a fixed value of the third (`c`).

Example usage, repeated `ezplot`:s for varying (fixed) values of `c`:

```
% plot 'Vg + L*c + 2 = 0' for values of c in [0,5]
hold on, box on
for c = 0:0.05:5
  ezplot(@(Vg,L)myfun(Vg,L,c))
end
```

[image]

---

As another alternative, you could simply use `subs(...)` for e.g. the `Vg` symbolic to plot the implicit function for the remaining two for varying (fixed) values of `Vg`:

```
syms Vg L a b z c
c=sym('a*Vg+z');
A=sym('a*Vg+b+c*L');
A=subs(A,[a b z],[1 2 3]);

hold on, box on
for VgVal = -6:6
  ezplot(subs(A, Vg, VgVal))
end
title([char(A), ', with Vg \in [-6, 6]'])
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot but I have too many parameters in my real equation 'the above is only an example' they are about 30 parameter not only k.                                         Is there a way to write them before the equation

Comment: @OmniaSamy If you're intended to use `ezplot`, you can only plot two of them at once (and add more plot for other fixed value sets for the remaining parameters). I'm not sure I understand what you mean by writing them before the equation?

Comment: I tried plot instead of ezplot like :                                                 f=@(L,Vg) ..........function in Vg, L, other constants..............

Lvals = linspace(0,100);

Vgvals = zeros(size(Lvals));

for j = 1:length(Lvals)

  Vgvals(j) = fzero(@(Vg) f(Lvals(j),Vg),0);

end                                                                                                             but the following error appear                                                                   
Undefined function or method 'plus' for input arguments of type 'function_handle'.

Comment: @OmniaSamy Before we continue, please read SO:s section [_How do I ask a good question_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It's not good practice to post a question, then repeatedly add details---that you initially left out---to comments of the answers. I will not put any more effort into this question until you know yourself (and can explain to us) what is is you're actually trying to achieve. Also, please don't add details as comments to this answer: update your question instead. Finally: have a look at Daniels comment to your question above; what is it you want to achieve here?